# Moodle, upload and store files using moodle forms

Tags: php, file-upload, moodle

I'm having some dificulties implementing a moodle upload mechanism using moodle forms. My goal is to let the user/administrator upload images, store them and access later in a block.

Currently, I have this in the form:

```
$mform->addElement('filemanager', 'attachments', 'Pic:', null, array('subdirs' => 0, 'maxfiles' => 1,'accepted_types' => '*' ));
```

and this to save the file:

```
if ($draftitemid = file_get_submitted_draft_itemid('attachments')) {
file_save_draft_area_files($draftitemid, $context->id, 'mod_assignment', 'attachments', 0, array('subdirs' => false, 'maxfiles' => 1));
}
```

and I try to access the file like this:

```
file_encode_url($CFG->wwwroot . '/pluginfile.php', '/' . $context->id . '/mod_assignment/attachments')
```

I don't receive any errors but I can't access the file either. I'm using moodle 2.0.

Thanks in advance,
Take care

Comment: Have you checked your error logs and enabled errors, perhaps you have a permissions problem.

Comment: Yes, it's a test server, errors are always enabled. I also check the logs and nothing there. I really don't understand.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are looking to write a custom block, in which case you should be giving **block_myblock** as the component name instead of **mod_assignment**.

Each Moodle component which serves files needs to have its own function defined within lib.php to handle file requests. In your case that function wants to be called something like `block_myblock_pluginfile()`.

A good example of this is `block_html_pluginfile()` which can be found in *moodle/blocks/html/lib.php* and does something very similar to what you are wanting.

Comment: Mark is right, you should take a look at https://docs.moodle.org/dev/File_API#Serving_files_to_users